# Add automatically one letter to different numbers in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have different numbers in attribute table to which I would like to automatically assign the same letter "E". I am using QGIS and I have tried using the field calculator but it did not work.

Comment: Well... what exactly have you tried? How does your data look currently, and how should the outcome look like? Which field type does your data have?

Comment: i have used string data to allow both numbers and letters in one column of my attribute table. For example I have different numbers 1200, 1288, 1258 and I would to assign the same letter E ( 1200E,1288E,1258E). Currently, I am doing it manually but it is hectic since I have a lot of different numbers. can I add the same letter E to different numbers automatically?

Comment: @do23 it would be better to add this additional information to your initial post (click `Edit` to do so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the attribute table, click Field Calculator, add a new field. Replace "id" with the name of your existing field.
Expression:

`concat("id", 'E')`

[image]